I want to make my Discord music bot run faster by starting to play the video while it's still loading. What can I do? (I’m new to coding)
I have a simple code like this, but the 'play' function takes around 10 seconds to execute. Would starting the music playback while it's loading make this code run faster?

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import yt_dlp
import os
import time
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())
current_speed = 1.0

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}!')

@bot.command(name="play")
async def play(ctx, url: str):

    start_time = time.time()

    global current_speed

    if not ctx.voice_client:
        if ctx.author.voice:
            channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
            message = await ctx.send("Loading music...")
            await channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.send("You're not in a voice channel!")
            return
    else:
        await ctx.voice_client.move_to(ctx.author.voice.channel)

    ffmpeg_path = "./ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe"

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '126',
        }],
        'outtmpl': "music",
        'ffmpeg_location': ffmpeg_path
    }

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts).download([url]))

    audio_source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(
        executable=ffmpeg_path, 
        source="music.mp3", 
        options=f"-filter:a 'atempo={current_speed}'"
    )

    if not ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
        ctx.voice_client.play(audio_source, after=lambda e: os.remove("music.mp3"))
        await message.edit(content=f"Started playing music.mp3!")
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot is currently playing another sound.")

    end_time = time.time()

    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    await ctx.send(f"Play command completed in {elapsed_time:.2f} seconds.")

    
bot.run("BOT_TOKEN")

Basically, I aim to start playing the audio while it's still loading, but I haven't found the right method for that. Initially, the 'download' process wasn't using 'asyncio':
with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([url])

I tried to do it with 'asyncio', but it didn't make much difference.

I aim to start playing the audio while it's still loading ... then ask about that

To make your Discord music bot start playing the audio while it's still loading, you can stream the audio directly from YouTube rather than downloading their respective files.
This is what you can do to modify your code:

Instead of downloading audio, you can stream it using yt_dlp with a streaming option.
Modify your FFmpegPCMAudio source to accept stream URLs directly into FFmpeg.

Your Code:
await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts).download([url]))
audio_source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(
    executable=ffmpeg_path, 
    source="music.mp3", 
    options=f"-filter:a 'atempo={current_speed}'"
)

Revised Code:
with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    info_dict = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
    audio_url = info_dict['url']
audio_source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(
    audio_url, 
    executable="./ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe", 
    options=ffmpeg_options
)

I would also recommend that when your music.mp3 is saved as a file and then deleted with os.remove("music.mp3"). I recommend removing this section of the code since you can stream it instead of running all the music locally.
